# How to align two 360 Cardboard Camera Images

Tags: computer-vision, virtual-reality

The program captures two time delayed 360 panoramas via Google Cardboard Camera.

While the two images have little or zero difference in position, each has random direction.

The idea is to auto align those two frames to have them looking in the same direction.

First idea is to pick a scanline at 10% and plot a contrast black and white strip for those frames and then compare them until best rotation match is found.

Comment: by compare, xor might be good to detect edges and then count differences on scan line

Comment: the two 360 frames may have different pixel width it seems. yay

Comment: the "difference" blending may give the best comparision